# Polylang plugin wordpress throwing error in widget area

Tags: wordpress, polylang

This is the error I am getting in the widget area I have defined for my language switcher:

> NOTICE: UNDEFINED INDEX: CODE IN
>   /HOME/DUTCHTAX/DOMAINS/DUTCHTAXADVICE.NL/PUBLIC_HTML/WP-CONTENT/THEMES/PATTI/FUNCTIONS.PHP
>   ON LINE 835 EN

```
// Language Switcher for WPML
if (!function_exists('delicious_language_selector')) {
    function delicious_language_selector() {
        if (function_exists('icl_get_languages')) {
            $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=code');
            wp_enqueue_script( 'dt-tipsy' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'dt-tipsy' );
            if(!empty($languages)){
                echo '<div id="header_language_list"><ul>';
                    foreach($languages as $l){
                        if($l['active']) { echo '<li class="active-lang switch-lang" original-title="'.$l['native_name'].'">'; }
                            else { echo '<li class="switch-lang" original-title="'.$l['native_name'].'">'; }
                        if(!$l['active']) echo '<a href="'.$l['url'].'">';
                            if($l['code'] != 'zh-hant') { echo substr($l['native_name'], 0, 2); } else { echo $l['native_name']; }
                        if(!$l['active']) echo '</a>';
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                echo '</ul></div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Already looked through all of that. not relevant to this question. worked absolutely fine before theme updated so no code has been touched.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Polylang's documentation](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/compatibility-with-the-wpml-api/), the **orderby** parameter only accepts *slug*, *name* or *id* as valid values. In the code above, you're passing *code*.

Try changing:

```
$languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=code');
```

to:

```
$languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=slug');
```

And:

```
if($l['code'] != 'zh-hant') { echo substr($l['native_name'], 0, 2); } else { echo $l['native_name']; }
```

to:

```
if($l['slug'] != 'zh-hant') { echo substr($l['native_name'], 0, 2); } else { echo $l['native_name']; }
```